# Динамическая подгрузка данных в фрагменты ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Имеется Activity с ViewPager и привязанным TabLayot. В зависимости от наличия/отсутствия данных для отображения формируются фрагменты. Один из фрагментов наследуется от ListFragment. А так, как для заполнения листа нужно данные брать с отдельного запроса, то возникла целесообразность подгружать их только в том случае, если пользователь перейдет на этот фрагмент. События OnCreate, OnResume, OnStart отрабатывают для этого фрагмента даже если он не выбран, а после добавления, вот код адаптера, добавляющий фрагменты:

```
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentsList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentsTitleList.add(title);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Как мне уловить событие реального выбора/отображения фрагмента?

Comment: попробуйте наследовать ваш viewpager adapter от FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а как наследовать? Не могли бы вы привести пример кода?

Comment: есть адаптер для viewpager он наследуется(extends) от FragmentPagerAdapter и метод addFragment() написан в адаптере. нужно просто заменить FragmentPagerAdapter на FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: Под вашим ответом есть кнопка <<править>>, воспользуйтесь пожалуйста. Комментарии мало кто читает.

Comment: помню я хотел узнать что такое FragmentStatePagerAdapter и чем отличается от FragmentPagerAdapter. и было сказано что он подгружает fragment'ы когда пользователь на него переключился

Answer (score 0):

на Англоязычном форуме [Muhammad Ashraf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3835368/muhammad-ashraf) подсказал

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        loadData();
    } else {
    }
}
```